# Coin Change : Find number of ways to reproduce a given sum

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, coin-change

> Given a value N, if we want to make change for N cents, and we have infinite supply of each of S = { S1, S2, .. , Sm} valued coins, how many ways can we make the change? The order of coins doesn’t matter.
>   For example, for N = 4 and S = {1,2,3}, there are four solutions: {1,1,1,1},{1,1,2},{2,2},{1,3}. So output should be 4. For N = 10 and S = {2, 5, 3, 6}, there are five solutions: {2,2,2,2,2}, {2,2,3,3}, {2,2,6}, {2,3,5} and {5,5}. So the output should be 5.

The Link of the Question is : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coin-change-dp-7/

I did come across all the solutions.

I've used the Matrix method to come up with a solution for this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <climits>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <queue>
#include <unordered_map>
#define ll long long
//Author: Nilargha Roy (neel13)
using namespace std;
int coinchangeways(int arr[],int n,int sum)
{

        int dp[n+1][sum+1];
        memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));


        for(int j=1;j<n;j++)
        {
            dp[0][j]=0;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            dp[i][0]=1;
        }



    for(int i=1;i<n+1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<sum+1;j++)
        {

            if(arr[i-1] <= j)
                dp[i][j]=dp[i][j-arr[i-1]] + dp[i-1][j];
            else
                dp[i][j]=dp[i-1][j];

        }
    }

    return dp[n][sum];

}

int main() 
{

    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
#endif
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>arr[i];
    int sum; cin>>sum;
    cout<<coinchangeways(arr,n,sum);
}
```

However, when I'm putting in an array = {1,2,3} and SUM = 5 as input, The Output should be : 5 while I'm getting 1. Can anyone pinpoint the logical error in my code?

Comment: You will have to try to find the logical error in your code using your debugger, that's what it's there for. Those meaningless online contest sites typically produce code that's hard for other people to read, and help you with, so you're on your own here. It's full of useless macros, and non-standard C++, like is the case here. You will find it beneficial to spend more time with a quality C++ textbook, studying core C++ concepts like natural 0-based array indexing. The shown code attempts to use unnatural 1-based array indexing, which just makes it even harder to read and understand its logic.

Comment: my new favorite punchline:  competitive coding to learn a language is like going to a punk concert to prepare for a waltz dancing contest. One bad thing about them is that they give you the impression that programming is about writing correct code. It is not. A tiny part of programming is writing code, and a huge part is debugging and testing. You wrote some code, now you need to do the rest also

Comment: @idclev463035818 sorry to burst your bubble but I wasn't using CP as a medium to learn any language, I simply wanted a helping hand with my solution. Thank you. God speed.

Comment: Try printing out the first line of your array after you've initialized it.

Comment: @PaulHankin I did. All good.

Comment: sorry, to burst your bubble, but using a debugger is an essential skill and it seems like you need to catch up on that.

Comment: Sorry for my previous erroneous comment. It seems that the "-1' are propagating through the DP array. You may try to initialize it to 0 and not -1

Comment: Are you aware that 1d-array is sufficient for this task?

Comment: @MBo Hey man Can you elucidate how ?

Comment: I added answer with 1d array code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you run your function after all of the for loop. you will have DP shown below.

```
 1   0   0  -1  -1  -1

 1   1   1   0  -1  -2

 1   1   2   1   1  -1

 -1  1   2   0   2   1
```

dp[3][5] = 1 that's why you are getting 1.

Comment: I realise I've initialized the first loop till n, instead of sum. Thank you so much. Godspeed.

Comment: you can also initialized you dp with 0 and remove first two for loop and just write dp[0][0] =1.

Answer (score 2):

Version that use 1d array:

```
int coinchangeways(int arr[], int n, int sum)
{
    int dp[sum+1];
    memset(dp, 0, sizeof(dp));
    dp[0] = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = arr[i]; j <= sum; j++)
        {
                dp[j] += dp[j - arr[i]];
        }
    }

    return dp[sum];
}
```